# Wonderware Historian SQL Server INSQL

Tags: sql-server, view

I am trying to get the definition of a view which contains historical values of different tags in Wonderware Historian. The target is to identify the source tables and enable CDC on those, in order to enable data streaming to a remote server. But when I look at view definition it shows something like

```
Select * 
From [INSQL].Runtime.dbo.History
```

But `History` is the view itself. Attached the image from DBeaver for this:

[image]

Any hints? Looks like it has something to do with this [INSQL]

Comment: Are you asking about INSQL specifically? That is the name of a linked server configured on the server you are querying

Comment: Yes you are right , INSQL is a linked server , now I need to see how to enable CDC for it or  how else I can achieve what I am trying to do .

Comment: _enable data streaming to a remote server_ No one but you really knows exactly what that means. Nor do I understand how CDC is related to "data streaming". Are you trying to replicate data?

Comment: Perhaps `SELECT m.definition FROM INSQL.Runtime.sys.views v JOIN INSQL.Runtime.sys.sql_modules m ON m.object_id = v.object_id WHERE v.name = 'History'`

Comment: @SMor yes we need to replicate the data into multiple tables i.e. split the data from this table to multiple tables based on certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

To find the tables referenced by a view a few options are available, probably the easiest is to use `sql_expression_dependencies`

```
select referenced_entity_name
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies 
where referencing_id=Object_Id('View name')
```